# Request product data with Ajax [Prestashop 1.7]

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, prestashop, product

I'am currently working on implementing Google Tag Manager on a prestashop boutique, and I was looking for a way to retrive product data from JS to send a dataLayer.
Is ajax the right way to do it ? And if so, how can I get product data (name, price, category, brand ....) from an ajax request ?

Thanks a lot,
Loic

Comment: Yes, Ajax is the way, have a look on my answer here, [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093865/prestashop-1-7-6-2-ajax-call-backoffice-module/65104911#65104911)

Comment: Hi @RobertinoVasilescu , thanks for your answer.
I'am not sure to fully understand the method to retrive product information in the answer you provided on the other thread. I'am looking for **getting** product information in JS by an ajax request. I'am a beginner in the domain, but i'am looking to do the following : 
Ajax request /w product_id => Sent to .php, proccessed to retrive product information (name, price, category, ect...) => Sent back to JS to create GoogleTagManager event with product info !
I'am really struggling doing it so I need a little kick to get into it..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to call a controller method with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: your_admin_controller_URL,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: {
                id_product: the _product_id_you want
            },
            success: (data) => {
                //do something
                });
            }
        });
```

Then in your admin controller (in your module) in a method specified in your_admin_controller_URL instantiate a product with

```
$product = new Product(id_product_from_ajax);
return $this->render('@Modules/your_module/views/admin_or_front/my_file.html.twig', [
product => $product]);
```

Then in your my_file.html.twig you have the product variable with all the data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help @Robertino, I tried this method creating a new product object
$product = new Product($id_product) but unfortunatly it does not work and return an error 500, I tried to return other values to my ajax request and it worked ! The only problem left is the new product method, any ideas on this ?

Comment: Look into the webserver (apache/nginx) log for the error (or use Prestashop Logger to log in Admin or write theerror to a log file in your module) and see what is it about. Are you sure you get the Id_product from ajax? And that it is an int? If you get something like "1" cast it to int with (int).